# php error logging not available for domain

Tags: php

I have my domain hosted on "Linux Basic Webhosting Plesk11 php 5.3.29". I recently took on a software update which incorporates recaptcha v2 into the guestbook. As a result we now get a blank frame on the page where the guestbook should be. We have checked files and verified the api keys from Google and have now been requested to provide the php error logs. We have found no error logs for php nor any php.ini files just the basic server logs reporting the error 500 code. Requested help from host company but got no-where as they say it's not their job to provide coding. Very helpful. I have checked php settings, error reporting is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED (Default), error logging is on. I need to get php error reporting working and would like a log file to appear in the ./ directory for the domain. Any help in setting this up would be great as this is beyond my experience.

Comment: You mentioned your basic server logs, the 500 code that it provides, what are the details on that?

Comment: [![log.jpg](https://s5.postimg.org/jb2ruskvr/log.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/fepfyszw3/)

Comment: So is guestbook.php which contains your recaptcha?

Comment: Yes, If I revert to the advanced V1 selection the guestbook appears as normal.

Comment: I checked out php settings some more last night (pushing my boundaries a bit more) and found the core settings "error_log" local and master had no value.